# What is the difference between .NET Framework 4.6.1 Targeting Pack and .NET Framework 4.6.1 Runtime?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, .net-4.6.1

I want to develop .net framework 4.6.1 applications using Visual studio 2012.So, I tried to install 4.6.1  developer pack for visual studio 2012.But when I go to this [link](http://getdotnet.azurewebsites.net/target-dotnet-platforms.html#) to install the framework.It provides me two links, one for .NET Framework 4.6.1 Targeting Pack and the other for .NET Framework 4.6.1 Runtime.
Which one of these shall I install?

Comment: The link you gave is to the developer pack, it includes the targeting pack, SDK and the 4.6.1 framework. So in short you need them all

Comment: Link to visual studio 2015 is also provided there.Do I  have to download that as well?

Comment: No, Looks like it is supported on VS2012, just make sure you download from the tab that has your version.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49978 to use .Net 4.6.1 in VS 2012, 2013, 2015.

Comment: Mark has already answered this. You need to install Developer Pack which should contain everything.
Link: http://getdotnet.azurewebsites.net/target-dotnet-platforms.html#

Select VS 2012 and download Targeting PAck

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To use the framework with Visual Studio 2012 or later install the developer type version.

The runtime type version is a lighter version, meant to run applications on servers. This runtime version doesn't have the information/extensions that Visual Studio needs, so Visual Studio can't use them.

Check why at [was-the-developer-pack-originally-called-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303219/was-the-developer-pack-originally-called-sdk)

**Update(2018-01-08)**

Currently, the download page is [.NET SDKs for Visual Studio](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/visual-studio-sdks).
First column has the Developer Pack versions, for Visual Studios, the middle column as the Runtime versions to install on production servers.

Comment: I'm afraid I felt it necessary to downvote because you don't actually explain what the targeting pack *is*.

Comment: Was not my intention to explain what it is but to responde to the question. Anyway, your comment make me notice that the answer could have a bit more information.

Comment: Not quite sure how you can avoid explaining the difference without explaining what it is, but up to you.

Comment: What's the difference between SDK and Targeting pack, I saw both options when trying to install .net framework 4.6.2 on VS 17

Comment: Where did you see it? the current page for download (just added on my update) doesn't mention any Targeting pack

Comment: Probably in the Visual Studio 2017 installer - there are currently some SDKs and targeting packs listed.

Comment: The gist of the question was, which one do I install?  That wasn't answered either so this thread is not particularly useful.