# Why I cannot choose target framework 4.7.1 but 4.7.2 is possible?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-framework-version

Hello I face since few month with a problem that I cannot use target framework 4.7.1 with Visual Studio 2017 (newest update). But I can use 4.7.2

I need it because I use Unity 3D which uses that target.

I made this steps.

- Download and install 4.7.1 DevPack and Runtime Installation
- Install missing components (like 4.7.1) in VS Installer
- Reinstall all (start with 4.7) net frameworks.
- Update VS Studio 2017 to the newest

But still is not there. Here some screenshots

[image: Target Frameworks in VS Studio 2017]
[image: Visual Studio Components]
[image: Programs / apps]

I don't know what else I can do. I hope I get some help here

Comment: Learn what is .NET Developer Pack and the answer is clear https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/guide-for-developers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Was the "Developer pack" originally called SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303219/was-the-developer-pack-originally-called-sdk)